# IE8 does not return selected text using mouse pointer

Tags: javascript

I'm using this code to select text from the window document. This code is working fine in all browsers: it returns the selected text, but in IE8 it does not give the selected text. Instead it gives the whole HTML of the selected line. Can anybody give me solution for this?

Example:

```
<B><U><SPAN style="LINE-HEIGHT: 150%; FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial',
'sans-serif'; FONT-SIZE: 12pt">Summary</SPAN></U></B>
```

I want only **Summary** so all major browser return this except IE8.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getSelectionText(id) {
        var html = "";
        if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
            var sel = window.getSelection();
            if (sel.rangeCount) {
                var container = document.createElement("div");
                for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                    container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
                }
                html = container.innerHTML;
            }
        } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
            if (document.selection.type == "Text") {
                html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
            }
        }
        document.getElementById(id).value = html;
        //document.getElementById(id).value = html;
    }       
</script>
```

Comment: You may find [`Rangy`](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/) useful.

Comment: Your example HTML is awful.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [rangy](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/) - A cross-browser JavaScript range and selection library. In their own words:

> It provides a simple standards-based API for performing common DOM Range and Selection tasks in all major browsers, abstracting away the wildly different implementations of this functionality between Internet Explorer up to and including version 8 and DOM-compliant browsers.

Comment: There are links to [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/DocumentationHome) and [demos](http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/index.html) on the page linked in the answer. And there is a [basic usage](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/#Basic_usage) section on the page as well.

Answer (score 0):

Change

> html = container.innerHTML;

into

> html = container.innerText;

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the following line in IE8

```
html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
```

Change it to this

```
html = document.selection.createRange().text;
```

Below is a nice simple function which seems to work well for me

```
function getSelectedText() {
  var txt = '';
  if (window.getSelection) {
    txt = window.getSelection();
  }
  else if (document.getSelection) {
    txt = document.getSelection();
  }
  else if (document.selection) {
    txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
  else return; 
  return txt;
}
```

Hope this helps